# Parallax Scrolling Effect like TodoMovies 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, parallax

I was wondering how I might go about implementing a scrolling parallax effect similar to what is seen in *TodoMovies 3*?

In *TodoMovies 3*, the background of (what I think is) a `UITableViewCell` moves faster than the scrolling of the page, making a really awesome effect.

How would you go about detecting the scroll of the TableView's scrollview and also adjust the background image of the cell in a performant way?

Or is the effect impossible to achieve with `UITableView`?

Comment: You could call a method in `layoutSubviews` of your `UITableView` to "scroll" the `UIImageView` shown. Or maybe check on CocoaControls if someone has done it and share it.

Comment: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/parallax-scrolling-collectionview/ may give you some ideas, it's built with UICollectionView but you can adapt in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to achieve the effect by placing this code in my UITableViewController

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for (TVTableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        [cell adjust:(cell.frame.origin.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
    }
}
```

And this code in my UITableViewCell

```
- (void)adjust:(CGFloat)offset {
    CGRect frame = self.image.frame;
    frame.origin.y = (offset / 10.0);
    self.image.frame = frame;
}
```

Modified from oleb.net/blog/2014/05/parallax-scrolling-collectionview. Thanks mustafabesnili for the link.

Comment: very easy and simple to use. Thanks